# What is "Credential name" parameter in Watson QA service dialogue?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, nlp-question-answering

Today I noticed for the first time that the dialogue for the Watson Question and Answer service has an extra field that I haven't seen in other services.

"Credential name"

- what is that used for?
- Why does it not exist for other services?
- Which services does it exist for?
- What is the cf-cli equivalent?

Comment: Can you add a picture of where you are looking at "credential name"?

Comment: I think this is related to recent changes in bluemix, see: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/07/07/bluemix-updates-one-year-anniversary/

Answer (score 3):

You can now create multiple credentials for a single service and provide a name for them.  As German suggested above, details are provided [in this post on new Bluemix updates](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/07/07/bluemix-updates-one-year-anniversary/).  For clarity, the "Credential Name" option is shown in this image of the Concept Insights service [image: image of the Concept Insights service].

Comment: Ah ha! There were a lot of updates there. I missed that one.